# select xml node with specific field value

Tags: c#, xml

I have have an xml file with patern:

```
    .....
<User>
    <Vorname>Bart</Vorname>
    <Name>Szop</Name>
    <StanDE>Zast</StanDE>
    <StanENG>Assistant</StanENG>
    <Tel>+49 9999999</Tel>
    <Kom>+49 0000000000</Kom>
</User>
...
...
<User>
    <Vorname>Arthur</Vorname>
    <Name>Karst</Name>
    <StanDE>Leiter</StanDE>
    <StanENG>Manager</StanENG>
    <Tel>+49 111111</Tel>
    <Kom>+49 000003333</Kom>
</User>
.....
```

I would like to select an user with specific name - lets say Karst and replace him with another user which will be created the following way:

```
XElement root = new XElement("User");
                root.Add(new XElement(nameof(user.Vorname), user.Vorname));
                root.Add(new XElement(nameof(user.Name), user.Name));
                root.Add(new XElement(nameof(user.StanDE), user.StanDE));
                root.Add(new XElement(nameof(user.StanENG), user.StanENG));
                root.Add(new XElement(nameof(user.Tel), user.Tel));
                root.Add(new XElement(nameof(user.Kom), user.Kom));
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: If you are replacing then find user and use Set Value : XElement user = root.Elements("User").Where(x => (string)x.Element("Vorname") == "Karst").FirstOrDefault();  user.Element("Vorname").SetValue(user.Vorname);